# document.getElementsByClassName doesn't work

Tags: javascript

```
function getHeight(element) {
    console.log(element);
    var offsetHeight = document.getElementsByClassName(element).offsetHeight;
    console.log(offsetHeight);
}
getHeight("card-1");
```

Although it correctly prints the element to the console with just `document.getElementsByClassName(element)` but I can't get to the offsetHeight property, even with `document.getElementsByClassName(element)[0].offsetHeight`

Do I have to run a loop?

Comment: `el.style.offsetHeight`?

Comment: @u_mulder doesn't work.

Comment: Without `[0]` it **shouldn't** work. You say you've tried it with though, and when [I do that](http://jsfiddle.net/4w9au6ow/), I can't reproduce the problem. The code you've shared with us is insufficient to demonstrate the issue. Try providing a complete, reduced test case.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/grht7ahc/   works!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`document.getElementsByClassName(element)` returns a `HTMLCollection` of elements. The collection doesn' t have an `offsetHeight` property, each element in the collection has.

Now if you want to get the `offsetHeight` of the first matched element you can simply use
`document.getElementsByClassName(element)[0].offsetHeight`

If you wanted the max or min `offsetHeight` of all the matched elements you'd need to iterate over the collection.

Comment: `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'offsetHeight' of undefinedpage1c.html?ckcachecontrol=1420794955:62 getHeightpage1c.html?ckcachecontrol=1420794955:65 (anonymous function)`

Comment: @3zzy which means that getElementsByClassName has returned an empty collection. Is it possible that the script is executed before the elements are in the document?

Comment: Ah yes, that was it. Placing the code at the end of body did the trick

Answer (score -1):

according to documentation https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/document.getElementsByClassName

```
document.getElementsByClassName(classNames)
```

returns a collection of html elements (actually instance of HTMLCollection)
So If you run this code it should work

```
    var collection = document.getElementsByClassName(classNames),
      offset = -1;

    if (collection.length > 0) {
      offset = collection[0].offsetHeight;
    }

    return offset;
```