# Select all tags within divs with certain class

Tags: javascript, tags, getelementsbytagname, getelementsbyclassname

I've been trying to find a solution to my problem for days now without any luck, I found this: [getElementsByClassName doesn't work](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27857095/document-getelementsbyclassname-doesnt-work) but it's not a solution to my problem since I want to access all tags and change them, so here we go:

I want to be able to change the style of tags that are within divs with a certain class. I started out by trying this with an ID on a div and that works exactly the way I want it, but since the page where I will use this will have the same div's appear several times I have to use class instead and I can't get it to work. I have to use javascript and not jQuery.

Example of how it worked with ID:

```js
var images = document.getElementById("test").getElementsByTagName("img");
for (var i = 0; i < images.length; i++) {
  images[i].align = "right";
}
```

```html
<div id="test">
  <img src="http://galerie32.de/images-designer/thumbs/dummy-user.jpg" width="100">
  <p>
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Etiam lobortis turpis justo, eu egestas elit aliquet sit amet. Vivamus convallis, dolor a euismod scelerisque, nisi lorem placerat nisi, sed euismod ligula eros in lorem. Pellentesque vel ante semper,
    convallis ante in, mollis odio.
  </p>
  <img src="http://galerie32.de/images-designer/thumbs/dummy-user.jpg" width="100">
  <p>
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Etiam lobortis turpis justo, eu egestas elit aliquet sit amet. Vivamus convallis, dolor a euismod scelerisque, nisi lorem placerat nisi, sed euismod ligula eros in lorem. Pellentesque vel ante semper,
    convallis ante in, mollis odio.
  </p>
</div>
```

Example of how I want it to work:

```js
var images = document.getElementsByClassName("test").getElementsByTagName("img");
for (var i = 0; i < images.length; i++) {
  images[i].align = "right";
}
```

```html
<div class="test">
  <img src="http://galerie32.de/images-designer/thumbs/dummy-user.jpg" width="100">
  <p>
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Etiam lobortis turpis justo, eu egestas elit aliquet sit amet.
  </p>
  <img src="http://galerie32.de/images-designer/thumbs/dummy-user.jpg" width="100">
  <p>
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Etiam lobortis turpis justo, eu egestas elit aliquet sit amet.
  </p>
</div>

<div class="test">
  <img src="http://galerie32.de/images-designer/thumbs/dummy-user.jpg" width="100">
  <p>
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Etiam lobortis turpis justo, eu egestas elit aliquet sit amet.
  </p>
  <img src="http://galerie32.de/images-designer/thumbs/dummy-user.jpg" width="100">
  <p>
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Etiam lobortis turpis justo, eu egestas elit aliquet sit amet.
  </p>
</div>
```

I understand that there should be a completely different way of writing the statement when I want to access the classes, but I can't figure out how.

Anyone who knows and can give me some pointers?

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/ge1Lmanv/  You need two loops, to get all elements....  getElementsByClassName returns HTML collection, and you can loop over it, too...

Comment: What do you get when you try this JavaScript? An error?

Comment: This would be way easier if you were to make proper use of the power of CSS selectors … like change the class name of a common ancestor element. and have a rule in your stylesheet that formats the descendant elements differently based on that.

Comment: Try `document.querySelectorAll('.test img')`

Comment: @nevermind - I was thinking that I maybe had to have a loop in a loop but couldn't get it to work. This works exactly the way I want it to! Super big thank you!

Comment: @CBroe - Yes, that would definitely be the best way. But where I want to use this I am not allowed to add my own stylesheet. Complicated to explain, but it's a complicated system I'm working in. It's at my job and they have built their own system with their own language, so I won't even use HTML when it's done ;) This is a page where people can add as many pictures as they want to, and thus I can't add a class to them since the user themselves add the images. But all images HAVE to appear on the right :)

Comment: _“and thus I can't add a class to them”_ – that was not what I meant anyway – CSS can select elements based on more than just a class. `#test img` would select all image elements inside your element with the ID `test` – and if you then add a class to that ancestor element via JS, you could simply use `#test.foo img { … }` to format them differently. (And an additional stylesheet containing the rules for that could be either dynamically inserted or created.)

Comment: @CBroe - Yes, that would be best. But in this system that is not possible. I would still use Javascript to add the class or id, and also Javascript to add the style. I can't add my own stylesheet, not with an external file or directly in the code or anywhere really. As I said, this system is a bit complicated ;) But thank you for the input!

Comment: @Tushar - I did not know you could use this and I will have to read more about the `querySelectorAll`. It sure seems to do what I want! I will either use this or what nevermind wrote. Big thank you!

Comment: @torazaburo - I had looked at that question before (added that info in this one). That person was looking for an output of something within a class ( still don't really understand what that question was about) and I was trying to access tags to change them. The answers in the other post did not help me at all. Now when I have answers in this post which have solved the problem and those answers are different from the ones in the other post I think it's important to keep this question open if other people have the same problem that I had.

Comment: @Emma Hi. The root cause of your problem is that you didn't realize that `getElementsByClassName` returns a node list, and can therefore not call `getElementsByTagName` on the result, and must loop over the nodes in it to do anything with them. This is the same root cause of the problem this is marked as a duplicate of (as well as many other questions posed here on SO--search for "getElementsByClassName not working". Questions need not be 100% precise duplicates to be closed as such; otherwise every single question such as "cannot use `getElementsByClassName` to make text red` would be unique.

Comment: @torazaburo - Ok, I get your point. I do however think that since the answers are so different and the answers in the other question did not solve this problem these should be seen as two separate questions. I did realize that the `getElementsByClassName` gave a list since I couldn't get it to work, I just didn't know how to solve it. For my sake it doesn't really matter if it's set as duplicate or not since I now know what to do :) For others it might be good to have it open though. I do appreciate people like you taking the time to administer things like this! Just some food for thought :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The code `document.getElementsByClassName("test")` gives you *a list of elements*, not *one element*. Do a loop (`for`) on these elements. In this loop, call `getElementsByTagName("img")`.

Comment: Thank you! This is what will solve my problem, got an example above from nevermind that I can use.